# Could two Mummy Lords fight each other based on a feud in their previous life?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, undead

From my understanding of the [Mummy Lord description in the *Monster Manual*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/mm/monsters-m#MummyLord) (p. 227), the ritual used to create the mummy allows it to keep all of its memory from before it was transformed.

I want to confirm that this means that if two enemies in life both get transformed into Mummy Lords, they both remember that they were enemies and even though they are both Mummy Lords now, they could continue fighting each other ("until death" Ha! Ha!) based on those memories.

Is this accurate?

Comment: Edited and reopened; “will they” is opinion and DM prerogative, but “could they” has rules support.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is very possible.

Very new players might imagine there was some sort of Evil Team (or Undead Team), where all the creatures that are hostile to humans have agreed that they're on the same team and not going to harm each other.  Of course this isn't true.

It is true that unintelligent undead usually don't attack each other -- often because they all want to feed on the living, but none of them are living, so they don't look appetizing to each other.

It's also true that D&D rarely features battles between opposing groups of NPCs, simply because that takes a lot of time to simulate and it's boring for the player characters if they have to sit back and watch it.

But mummy lords have a human-like intelligence, so they can have real motives and might choose to attack each other.

(Of course, they might also choose to do something else, such as ally with each other in the face of a greater threat.)